# Apache spark CPU performance not scaling linearly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to write a simple benchmark for apache spark to use to compare performance between servers.

Currently I'm trying to compare CPU performance. I have written a simple benchmark that generates prime numbers in parallel.

I have the following script that either runs with 1, 64, 128 or 256 partitions and I also limit the number of executor cores with spark-submit to prevent the kernel from allocation additional cores like follows:

```bash
./bin/spark-submit --total-executor-cores x --master spark://server:7077 generate_primes_x.py
```

However given that prime number generation is so simple I would expect the scaling to be somewhere in the realm of O(2N) however that's not what I'm seeing.

[image: results]

The script in question is as follows (where numSlices is modified for the number of desired partitions 1,64,126,256):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("ParallelPrimeGenerator_256") \
        .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext

    upper_limit = 10000000

    # Create an RDD with numbers from 2 to upper_limit
    numbers_rdd = sc.parallelize(range(2, upper_limit + 1), numSlices=256)  # You can adjust the number of slices

    # Filter the prime numbers using the is_prime function
    prime_numbers_rdd = numbers_rdd.filter(is_prime)

    # Collect the prime numbers and print them
    prime_numbers = prime_numbers_rdd.collect()
    print("Prime numbers up to", upper_limit, ":", prime_numbers)

    spark.stop()
```

Why isn't this scaling linearly with the number of cores/partitions?

Comment: try increasing upper_limiit to something far higher and see the results, at 19s the cost is probably more on handling of data than the actual running of the is_prime

Comment: How does it scale? It doesnt , it stays flat. Means there are other limiting factors.